# I am trying to debug my PowerShell but I cannot get anything to output

Tags: powershell

I have this script here:

```
Write-Host "Checking files"

#to make it more dynamical you can save on one file
#all the file names including extension in different lines.
#For example on path C:\FilesToWatch\watcher.txt
#$filestowatch=get-content C:\FilesToWatch\watcher.txt

#$filestowatch="felicio.txt","marcos.txt"
$userFiles=dir C:\G\user\less\
$adminfiles=dir C:\G\admin\less\

#Optionally instead of use this if approach you can 

#$adminfiles=dir C:\GT\admin\src\admin\wwwroot\content\less|? {$filestowatch -contains $_.Name}
#$userFiles=dir  C:\GT\user-staging\src\user-staging\wwwroot\content\less|? {$filestowatch -contains $_.Name}

#loading in the above manner the first if statement on code bellow can be removed because 
#We make sure that $userFiles and $adminfiles only have correct file to monitor

foreach($userfile in $userFiles)
{
   if($filestowatch -contains $userfile.Name)
   {
      $exactadminfile= $adminfiles | ? {$_.Name -eq $userfile.Name} |Select -First 1
       #my suggestion is to validate if it got the file.
       #By now because of my lazy i will not call the test-path to validate if it got the file
       #I'm assuming all directory are exact copy of each other so it will find the file.

      if($exactadminfile.LastWriteTime -gt $userfile.LastWriteTime)
      {
         Write-Verbose "Copying  $exactadminfile.FullName to $userfile.FullName "
         Copy-Item -Path $exactadminfile.FullName -Destination $userfile.FullName -Force
       }
       else
       {
          Write-Verbose "Copying  $userfile.FullName to $exactadminfile.FullName "
          Copy-Item -Path $userfile.FullName -Destination $exactadminfile.FullName -Force
       }
    }
}
```

I understand there may be a problem with the script but when it runs I do not even see the output from the first line.  Can anyone give me ideas on how can I debug this?

Here's how I run (or try to run the script):

```
  PS C:\GT> .\watcher.ps1
```

When I tried a script with just the first line only it worked okay. Is there a way that I can run this script in debug mode so it would give me an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open this script up in the ISE so you can use the debugger. Select a line that you want to set a breakpoint at and hit F9 to set it. Go ahead and run the script and once it gets to that line, it will break into the debugger. From there you can start to inspect your variables and step through the code to hopefully locate the issue.

Some ISE Debugger Shortcuts:

- F5 - Run/Continue
- F11 - Step Into
- F10 - Step Over
- F11 - Step Out
- CTRL+SHIFT+D - Display Call Stack
- CTRL+SHIFT+L Display Breakpoints
- F9 - Toggle Breakpoint
- CTRL+SHIFT+F9 - Remove all breakpoints
- SHIFT+F5 - Stop Debugger

More info on debugging can be found in the help files.

```
Get-Help about_debuggers
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  I am very new to PowerShell. What is ISE ?

Comment: I would suggest reading [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/07/learn-how-to-use-the-free-powershell-ise-to-edit-scripts.aspx) on using the PowerShell ISE.

Comment: @boeprox Sadly your link is dead : (

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3) should work.

Comment: More like: from there you can attempt to run commands and when they fail, Powershell will arbitrarily decide to unbreak from where it's broken in your script executing the remainder of it without even asking and failing to even give you an error message as to why the command you ran apparently failed!